# Solution of Non linear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know that theory of nonlinear pde is quite vague and depends upon problem to problem. I want to know if some how we get any particular solution of pde then is there any method to find the general solution.

Comment: In the general case, the answer is "no"

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases (except for some very specific PDEs), you do not have a formula for a general solution. That's why we have numerical analysis. We transform the complicated PDE into discrete time equations and we run this in a computer simulation. In some cases, you can tell precisely the difference between the simulation and the PDE.